# Swing component add to ScrollPane(JavaFX)

Tags: java, swing, pdf, javafx

I'm making JavaFX application which will open pdf files. I found free library for PDF Viewer but it's made in Swing. So I need to add JPanel to ScrollPane(JavaFX). I tried but without success.

I got this error:

Aug 13, 2016 9:59:09 PM org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Document 
WARNING: PDF write support was not found on the class path.

I found here on stackoverflow how to add swing component to javafx pane and I do that but I got this error.

Any suggestion is welcome.

```
package application;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.icepdf.ri.common.ComponentKeyBinding;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

    public class PDFView{

    public JPanel viewerComponentPanel;

    public static Node showPDF(File sFiles) throws MalformedURLException {

    String filePath = sFiles.toURI().toURL().toString();

    // build a controller
    SwingController controller = new SwingController();

    // Build a SwingViewFactory configured with the controller
    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

    // Use the factory to build a JPanel that is pre-configured
    //with a complete, active Viewer UI.
    JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

    // add copy keyboard command
    ComponentKeyBinding.install(controller, viewerComponentPanel);

    // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
    controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
          new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                 controller.getDocumentViewController()));


    final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode, viewerComponentPanel);


    // Open a PDF document to view
    controller.openDocument(filePath);
    return swingNode;

}

 private static void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode, JPanel viewerComponentPanel) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             swingNode.setContent(viewerComponentPanel);
         }
     });
 }

}
```

This is main class where I call the method from PDFView class

```
for(int i=0;i<fileNumber;i++){

        choosedName=sFiles[i].getName();
        String ext=choosedName.substring(choosedName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        switch (ext) {
        case "doc":  
                 break;
        case "docx": 
                 break;
        case "pdf":                  

            tab = new Tab();
            tab.setText(choosedName);
            s1=new ScrollPane();
            tab.setContent(s1);
            s1.setContent(PDFView.showPDF(sFiles[i]));
        tpane.getTabs().add(tab);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded icepdf [viewer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/icepdf/icepdf-viewer.jar.zip) and [core](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/icepdf/icepdf-core-4.3.3.jar.zip) jars.
and a minimal change in your code:

```
//String filePath = sFiles.toURI().toURL().toString();
String filePath = sFiles.getAbsolutePath();
```

then, it worked for me, hope also works for you...

Comment: Is it possible to change the frame size inside my application. When i maximize my application, frame inside it for PDF don't do that like frame of my application. http://prntscr.com/c5mwnl

Comment: using swingnode with some heavyweight swing components (with also jpanel) has known issues. you may prefer using  [javafx based pdf viewers](https://www.google.com.tr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=eMCwV6-sF6zY8AfYroHwDw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=strict&q=javafx+pdf+viewer).

Comment: do you have any suggestions?